# PHP Mysqli SELECT from Views doesn't works

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I've created a very simple view on my MySQL database, through PHPMyAdmin.
The View is perfectly working, for now it's only:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

In PHPMyAdmin I can see all the record selected by this query.

In my PHP code, I'm using the following code:

```
 $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM MyTable");
 $stmt->execute()
 .......
```

This perfectly working, I can read all the records, but if I write:

```
 $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM MyView");
 $stmt->execute()
 .......
```

I obtain 0 records.

I'm just repeating:

- The View is perfectly working, it's really simple for now, just a SELECT * FROM MyTable;
- My PHP code is perfectly working when I select from a table, but seems to doesn't works when I select from a View.

What's wrong?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: The exception is the following:

**Type:** mysqli_sql_exception

**Code:** 1615

**Message:** Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared

Comment: The error mode for `$this->conn` is set to [PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)?

Comment: @VolkerK It looks like OP's using mysqli_.

Comment: You are right, Fred.

Comment: Oh, right. Do you set `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT|MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);` somewhere? Otherwise your script lacks error handling (and thus nobody knows what's going on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read that is a **mysqli** problem.

So I switched to **PDO** and now is perfectly working.

Comment: Hi, I might be facing the same problem. Could you recall where you read that it was a mysqli problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

We suspect that an error is occurring when the SQL statement is prepared, or executed.

We suspect that your code is not checking for error conditions. (There's no indication of such checks in the code snippets that are posted.)

We recommend you first fix that in your code.

As far as what error is occurring, there is insufficient information to diagnose  that. You say that the *exact* same SQL text being run by the PHP code, executes successfully in another environment. That excludes problems with case sensitivity in the identifier (view name) `myview` vs `MyView`. We're guessing that you are connecting to the same database, with the same MySQL user (user and host) from both environments, which rules out a difference in privileges.

Comment: The Exception is:
Type: mysqli_sql_exception
Code: 1615
Message: Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared